Why are not relevant search queries in local search capitalized?
I found an interesting relationship between relevant and not relevant search queries and the way they are written.
Let's say I have a website about fruit and vegetables. When I look in my statistics, some of my search queries are relevant:

apples
pear
pineapple

And some queries are not relevant:

Car
Boat
Airplain

The not relevant search queries are most of the time written capitalized. If you ask me this can not be a coincidence. But why is this happening? Is this a bot asking questions? Are queries entered using a other website? Google maybe?
